# Help with changing slider colors on an iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, colors, slider

I need to change slider colors in my iphone app, and I put This:

```
- (UISlider *)ratioSlider
{

        UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayslide.png"]
                                    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
        UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayslide.png"]
                                     stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
        [ratioSlider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_ball.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [ratioSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [ratioSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

in the "myVIewController.m" file, like in the UICatalog apple example file. I've added all of the images and defined the slider, but all that comes up on the simulator is a normal slider, and the only error/warning in XCode is a warning saying "Warning: control reaches end of non-void function". How do I get this code to work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the warning:

> Warning: control reaches end of
>   non-void function

Is because your not returning an object of type UISlider * based on your message signature:

```
- (UISlider *)ratioSlider
```

Comment: I tried changing it to a void action, but the images still don't show up on the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I think you gone the wrong way around.

Instead of trying to change it to a void action, why don't you

`return ratioSlider;`

at the end of your method.

(Don't forget to checkout the `viewDidLoad` method on ControlsViewController.m in UICatalog to see how the customSlider is actually created, as this may also be confusing matters).

Comment: I added a return `ratioSlider;` at the end, but it still doesn't work.
In the `viewDidLoad` of UICatalog, there is: `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         @"UISlider", kSectionTitleKey,
         @"Customized Slider", kLabelKey,
         @"ControlsViewController.m:\r-(UISlider *)customSlider", kSourceKey,
         self.customSlider, kViewKey,
       nil],` I'm kind of a newbie at obj-c, so I'm not exactly sure what that means, but it looks like it's mostly defining text.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you add the ratioSlider @property in the .h file?

Comment: the ratioSlider @property in the .h looks like this: `@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) UISlider *ratioSlider;` - the only difference between it and the UICatalog file is the slider name(Which I changed everywhere else, too).